# Problems with Totalview debugging software on OSX

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, totalview

I am trying to do some multithreaded debugging on OSX. I had initially attempted to use GDB through the QtCreator IDE, however I never could get this to work exactly right. I am using the Totalview evaluation right now, and as soon as I point it to my executable, I get the following

```
Reading symbols for runtime loader /usr/lib/dyld(x86_64)
Error reading one of the dynamic loader image info values
Error reading one of the dynamic loader image info values
WARNING: Entrypoint address 0x7fff5fc01028 in library '/Users/dec/work/exc1' appears invalid
```

where exc1 is my executable. What do those messages mean? How do I resolve the problem? I am tagging GDB here just in case

Answer (score 0):

> What do those messages mean?

That TotalView had a problem with your `/usr/lib/dyld`.

> How do I resolve the problem?

Contact TotalView tech support?